# Only NodeJS v6.17.1 can be installed

Tags: node.js, linux

I want to install the latest NodeJS on Amazon Linux 2, but can only install v6.17.1.
I saw [nodesource/distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions-1) and tried to install the latest NodeJS. The command at that time is as follows.

```sh
[root@ip-]# curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 13.x repo...
## Inspecting system...
~~~
## Run `sudo yum install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 13.x and npm.
## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
     sudo yum install gcc-c++ make
## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
     curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
     sudo yum install yarn
```

```
[root@ip-]# yum install -y nodejs

Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration
198 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 2:6.17.1-1nodesource will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

============================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                     Arch                                        Version                                                      Repository                                       Size
============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 nodejs                                      x86_64                                      2:6.17.1-1nodesource                                         nodesource                                       13 M

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 13 M
Installed size: 39 M
Downloading packages:
nodejs-6.17.1-1nodesource.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                 |  13 MB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : 2:nodejs-6.17.1-1nodesource.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/1
  Verifying  : 2:nodejs-6.17.1-1nodesource.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/1

Installed:
  nodejs.x86_64 2:6.17.1-1nodesource

Complete!
```

```sh
[root@ip-]# node --version
v6.17.1
```

In this way, only v6.17.1 can be installed.
How can I install the latest version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sorry, it seems that I was doing something other than what I wrote here.
Installation was successful when the instance was rebuilt.

Comment: What you did differently? I am having similar issues with AWS and node 6.17.1

Comment: Please, what did you do?